# how do i cache a variable every 24 hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query with horrible performance:

```
select COUNT(distinct accession_id) count,MONTH(received_date) month,YEAR(received_date) year
into #tmpCounts
from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
where CLIENT_ID not in (select clientid from SalesDWH..TestPractices)
group by MONTH(received_date),YEAR(received_date)
```

Instead of waiting for this query, I would like to create a variable or a view or anything else that I can store on the server and have the server automatically calculate it every 24 hours.

I would like to then be able to do a `select * from #tmpCounts`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this meets your need, but I would create a table for storing it, use SQL Server Agent to create a job that just truncates the table, runs the query you mention above and inserts the rows.  This way from then on you could query the table for those results.

As an aside, likely the easiest way to truncate and load the table would be running a very simple SSIS package.

Comment: As a slight variation, the cache table can contain a `DATETIME` column to record when the summary was obtained.  The scheduled job can add a new summary, then delete any older data from the table.  That way clients will always have a result available.  This technique can also be used when you are sometimes willing to wait for a result.  A client accesses the cache via a stored procedure.  The SP checks the age of the cached data and, if needed, refreshes the data.  A client may have to wait on occassion, but the overhead of frequently updating the cache when no one is looking may be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your issue of performance and trying an alternative to prebuild each time once per day... How many records are you dealing with for this query to process.

In addition, I would alter the query since IN ( SUBSELECT ) are ALWAYS horrible.  I would change to a LEFT-JOIN to the client table and test for NULL or not

```
select 
      YEAR(FAD.received_date) year,
      MONTH(FAD.received_date) month,
      COUNT(distinct FAD.accession_id) count
   from 
      F_ACCESSION_DAILY FAD
         LEFT JOIN SalesDWH..TestPractices TP
            on FAD.Client_ID = TP.ClientID
   where 
      TP.CLIENT_ID IS NULL
   group by 
      YEAR(FAD.received_date),
      MONTH(FAD.received_date)
```

I would also ensure having an index on your ACCESSION table on received_date, and your TestPractices table on its ClientID

Comment: thanks so much for your answer! i'm processing approximately 10m records

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a cache table, consider creating an indexed view.  There are limitations, but you may be able to improve your performance dramatically without much extra processing or code.

Here's some basic information to start with:

http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/tsql/2011/questions/advantage-and-disadvantage-of-using-indexed-view-in-sql-server.aspx